# Android: Change text in a PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a MainActivity which calls a fragment (ReadStory).
ReadStory has a ViewPager which uses a PagerAdapter.
The page has an image and a TextView at the bottom. (This example only shows the TextView)

All of this works well.

There's a requirement that when the user touches/clicks the TextView various words are highlighted in red. This also works well.

The problem I have is that the text (with red highlights) is displayed on the next screen not the current visible screen.
I have set a onClickListener on the TextView which sets the relevant parts to red and then sets the text on the TextView.

The ViewPager loads the current screen plus the previous and next screens. The TextView is 'attached' to the "nextScreen".

How do I change the TextView on the current screen?

I've searched for the answer for several days but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

My code - MainActivity

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button myButton;
ReadStory RS;

// *********************************************************************************************

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(textViewClickListener);

}

// *********************************************************************************************

private View.OnClickListener textViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int[] mStory_resources = {R.string.S1P0, R.string.S1P1, R.string.S1P2, R.string.S1P3, R.string.S1P4, R.string.S1P5, R.string.S1P6, R.string.S1P7,
                R.string.S1P8, R.string.S1P9, R.string.S1P10, R.string.S1P11};
        int mStoryWords = R.string.S1words;

        RS = new ReadStory();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putIntArray("Story", mStory_resources);
        args.putInt("storyWords", mStoryWords);
        RS.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack("readStory");
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, RS);
        ft.commit();

    }
};
// *********************************************************************************************
}
```

ReadStory

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ReadStory extends Fragment {

static String currentString = "";
static String newString = "";
private static final String story = "Story";
private static final String storyWords = "storyWords";
private int[] mStory_resources;
private int mStory_words;

ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

public ReadStory() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// *********************************************************************************************

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mStory_resources = getArguments().getIntArray(story);
        mStory_words = getArguments().getInt(storyWords);
    }

}

// *********************************************************************************************

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.read_story, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(getActivity());

    adapter.story_resources = mStory_resources;
    adapter.story_words = mStory_words;
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentString = getString(mStory_resources[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    return parent;

}

// *********************************************************************************************

}
```

PagerAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

int[] story_resources;
int story_words;
private TextView textView;
private Context ctx;

CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

// *********************************************************************************************

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return story_resources.length;
}

// *********************************************************************************************

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==object);
}

// *********************************************************************************************

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")                        // Put here as setText is deprecated as of API 16 - Jelly_bean
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    textView.setText(story_resources[position]);
    textView.setOnClickListener(textViewClickListener);

    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

// *********************************************************************************************

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);

}

// *********************************************************************************************

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")                        // Put here as fromHtml is deprecated as of API 24 - N

private View.OnClickListener textViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String patternString = "\\b(" + ctx.getString(story_words) + ")\\b";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ReadStory.currentString);
        StringBuffer bufStr = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String rep = matcher.group();
            matcher.appendReplacement(bufStr, "<font color='#EE0000'>" + rep + "</font>");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(bufStr);
        ReadStory.newString = bufStr.toString();

        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ReadStory.newString));
        } else {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ReadStory.newString));
        }

        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

// *********************************************************************************************


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
((TextView)v).setText(Html.fromHtml(ReadStory.newString));
```

instead of

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ReadStory.newString));
```

There is reference problem with textView object it consists reference of next item.